# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sybase/jdbcx/SybConnection weblogic

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, sybase, weblogic-10.x

I am getting below error when I call my rest web service which uses a Sybase DB on WebLogic 10.3.5. I have a JNDI data source defined, I tested the connection and it was succesfull.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sybase/jdbcx/SybConnection
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:630)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineCodeGenClass(GenericClassLoader.java:523)
    at weblogic.utils.classfile.utils.CodeGenerator.generateClass(CodeGenerator.java:73)
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.generateWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:340)
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:244)
    at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:190)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory$1.run(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory.getWrapper(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:161)
    at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.allocateConnection(Driver.java:251)
    at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.connect(Driver.java:164)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.getNonTxConnection(Driver.java:651)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.connect(Driver.java:127)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:364)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.getSqlSession(SqlSessionUtils.java:116)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:333)
    at $Proxy102.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:38)
    at $Proxy103.getAssetMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.pbc.service.AssetController.GetHashMap(AssetController.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sybase.jdbcx.SybConnection
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    ... 61 more
```

jconn3.jar is there in classpath and also I am seeing it getting loaded when server starts.
I am helpless, I search everywhere but in vain.

Comment: I don't know what the `jconn3.jar` is. Have you checked if it contains `com/sybase/jdbcx/SybConnection`?

Comment: yes, I verified that it contains SybConnection.

Comment: The problem is very clear: Your application does not have that class on its class path.  I'm not terribly familiar with WebLogic, but have you tried putting jconn3.jar inside of your WEB-INF/lib directory and seeing what happens?  If it spits out the same error, then you have more problems than you think.  If it doesn't, then the problem is in the applications classpath settings - would refer you to Weblogic documentation at that point.

Comment: @Mike : I have placed jconn3.jar in web-inf/lib, still same issue. Dont know what to do?

Comment: Again - I'm not terribly familiar with WebLogic.  Open up your copy of jconn3.jar to verify that the com.sybase.jdbcx/SybConnection.class file does exist.  If it does, then the only thing I can think of is to move the jar file from your WEB-INF/lib directory and into your WebLogic server's lib directory (similar to Tomcat's %CATALINA_HOME%/lib which is loaded for all contexts).  The bottom line is that your application can't find that class, which means its either not in the jar or the jar isn't on the classpath.